# Angular 7 Styles are applied only after I press a key example control f12, also it works if the component is at app.module level

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

Angular 7 is not applying styles, unless I press f12. Also the code does work if the component is at the app.module level. Nested module code does not apply the svg styles. I have Angular 7 + d3js + svg

You can take this demo code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-graph-demo
and move the code to another module, basically remove from app.module and add it to another module, then display it as a component in app.component.html,by adding the selector.
I have the following on my component. 
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

I have also tried moving the css outside the component, input index.html or new style.css, but nothing helps.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I think you are having problems with the way angular applies the styles. You should take a look at **angular css encapsulation**. I'm not sure what's the exact problem and what's the desired behaviour.